# Elementary OS different wallpapers on each monitor

Tags: elementary-os, multi-monitor, wallpaper, pantheon

I have a dual monitor setup and I'd like to have a different wallpaper for each monitor. I found two programs in this post: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/ubuntu-multi-monitor-tweaks-full-screen.html

Neither of them work for elementary OS. Does anyone know of program or settings to change to make this possible?

Comment: try variety desktop changer?

Comment: I installed it and looked in the options, it doesn't look like there's an option in there for dual monitors.

Comment: Have you tried to setup a single huge wallpaper and then tile it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HydraPaper. It's available to install with `flatpak`. To install it on Elementary OS you need first to install `flatpak`:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt install flatpak`

`flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`

Then you can install HydraPaper by running:

`flatpak install flathub org.gabmus.hydrapaper`

To run the program just run:

`flatpak run org.gabmus.hydrapaper`

The next time when you login to your system you will find the program in your application menu.